# Refreshing FTP server without pressing refresh

Tags: c++, server, ftp, refresh

I'm programming a C++ project that captures an image and automatically uploads it to an FTP server. The images are successfully being uploaded and I can see them by refreshing the FTP server web page.
My question is, whether is it possible to refresh the ftp server webpage without pressing the refresh button? Like to run a c++ code to refresh the specific page i'm working on?

Comment: Don't you just need a auto refresh plugin for your browser?  They make those already.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the client interface?

Answer (score 0):

The FTP protocol has no concept of notifications, so there is no way for an FTP server to make an FTP client automatically refresh a listing when the content of a directory changes.  The client needs to re-poll the listing periodically.  A web browser won't do that automatically, you would have to write/find a browser plugin to force it.  Or stop using a web browser to display an FTP server's listing, use an actual FTP client instead, preferably one that has timer capabilities built-in.